# How to get data-icon from anchor tag?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="measureControl" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" id="measureButton" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
</div>
```

When anchor clicked I need to get data-icon attribute and to set another data-icon (for example **eye**).

I try this:

```
  $("#measureButton").click(function () {
        var el = $(".ui-icon", this);
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        if (el.hasClass("home")) {
            el.removeClass("home");
            el.addClass("eye");
            output.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            measureControls.line.deactivate();
            el.removeClass("eye");
            el.addClass("home");
            output.style.display = "none";
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Any idea how can I implement it using jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: bind click event `on` <a>. Use `this` to get the clicked element reference and `data` to get data-* attribute value.

Answer (score 2):

just use jquery `.data` function

```
 $("#measureButton").click(function () {
       var currentIcon = $(this).data('icon');
       alert(currentIcon);
       $(this).data('icon','eye');
       var currentIcon = $(this).data('icon');
       alert(currentIcon);
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qs9zwwo0/

Comment: @Michael and I did some changes in the answer ;)

Comment: @Michael I added a fiddle check it

Comment: The icon dosen't change after I click on the house.

Comment: @Michael did you check my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

user jquery attr function to get the attributes value.

```
     $("#measureButton").click(function () {
      //to get the data icon.
      alert($(this).attr('data-icon'));

      // to set data icon
      $(this).attr('data-icon','eye');


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is very simple with pure JavaScript.

```
var iconData = measureButton.dataset.icon;
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tushar indicated:

```
$(document).on("click", "#measureButton", function(){
  $(this).attr("data-icon", "eye").button( "refresh" );
});
```